# Too many kde-frameworks-5-qt-x-y-z-core20 folders in /snap directory

Tags: kde, snap, disk-usage, qt, qt5

On my Ubuntu machine, I have KDE and Gnome, right now I only use the latter.

My `/snap` directory contains a number of packages with names like `kde-frameworks-5-qt-x-y-z-core20`, each over 1 GB. There is also `qt515-core20` which is almost 2 GB.

Can I delete some of the `kde-frameworks-5-qt-x-y-z-core20` folders, leaving only the latest?

Comment: This qestion is hard to asnswer given the amount of info provided. Are there any programs that depend on those `kde-frameworks...`? You can just try `sudo snap remove kde-frameworks-5-qt-x-y-z-core20`, and let us know what happened.

Comment: How can I check if any programs depend on those frameworks?

Comment: You can use `snap list` to list installed programs, and then `snap info --verbose program-name`. Look for the line that says `base: `.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So for the info for `base:` is `core 18`, `core 20`, and `core 22`, for different apps. So if I have `kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-5-core20` and  `kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20`, should it be safe to delete to lower numbered directory?

Comment: `snap connections | grep XYZ` seems to be a better way of finding dependencies.